# Making the functions of a checkbox work when it is preloaded in the from in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

From a previous form, I have a variable set to a `true` if Europe is selected in the ComboBox.

When the next from loads I need the Europe checkbox to be already checked and for it to show two radio buttons.

This is the code I currently have down which checks the checkbox but doesn't show the two radio buttons

```
    If blnEurope = True Then
        ckboxEurope.Checked = True

        rbExamFailE.Show()
        rbWintersportsE.Show()
    End If
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You mean that you have *two* variables?   One in the "previous form" and one in this form class?  What does the debugger tell you about the value of bInEurope?  Use the constructor or a public property to pass data from one class to another.

Comment: blnEurope is declared as a public variable in a module i created, the main issue lies in the fact that the checkbox is checked when the form is loaded, it is just not carrying out the function of that checkbox which is to display 2 radio buttons?

Comment: Are your radio buttons placed in the designer or created at runtime?

Comment: The radio buttons are hidden when the form loads and when the checkbox is checked they're shown by using .hide() and .show()

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting a variable that can be accessed by the next form to indicate that Europe was selected.

The given code is a little vague, and I'm not great at VB.net, here is how I would attempt it.

```
If blnEurope = True Then
    ckboxEurope.Checked = True

    Dim isEurope as Boolean = True

    Dim formToCreate as new NextForm(isEurope)
    formToCreate.Show()
End If
```

Comment: It is declared as a public variable so it can be accessed by all the forms, the checkbox in the form is checked once the form is opened but the checkbox isn't carrying out its function of displaying the two radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem which ended up being that in the form_load I had all radio buttons hidden along with the Europe radio buttons being shown under the condition that if blnEurope was true they were to be shown. Thanks everybody for trying to help!